# Evaluate $S = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{4n+1} + \frac{1}{4n+3} \right) $ by residues.

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification, residue-calculus

Today's [Michael Penn video](https://youtu.be/qoQ2pQi7mvM) was about evaluating the following sum, attributed to Newton:

$$ S = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{4n+1} + \frac{1}{4n+3} \right) $$

He attacks this by expressing the sum as an integral and uses partial fractions. I commented that I expected a use of the residue theorem, and decided to attack it as follows.

It can be shown that $$S = \int_0 ^1 \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \ dx$$ by some manipulation, as seen in the video. Let $u = \frac{1}{x}$ so $du = -\frac{1}{x^2} \ dx.$ Then the integral becomes

$$ S = \int_1 ^\infty \frac{1+u^2}{1+u^4} \ du. $$

Adding the two gives that

$$ I = 2S = \int_0 ^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \ dx. $$

Let $f(z) = \frac{1+z^2}{1+z^4}.$ Observe that $f$ has a 1st-order pole at $e^{i\pi/4}$ with residue $P$, computed as

$$ P = \frac{1 + e^{\pi i/2}}{(e^{\pi i/2} + i)(2e^{\pi i/4})} = -\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}}. $$

Now we consider

$$ I = \int_{C_R} f(z) \ dz$$

where $C_R$ is the quarter circle of radius $R$ in the first quadrant. I'll wave my hands at the usual argument (integrate on the real and imaginary axes and show the integral over the arc is zero by the usual $ML$ estimate), but we conclude that

$$ I = 2\pi i \left(- \frac{i}{2\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$

and thus $$\boxed{S = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}}$$

Is this a valid use of the residue theorem? I'll admit my complex analysis is a little rusty, but I wanted to brush up on some tricks.

I'll remark that this was also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784702/sum-of-this-series-sum-n-1-infty-1n-1-frac14n-3-frac14n-1?noredirect=1) but that solution still relies on the partial fractions method and the $\psi_0$ function.

Comment: Using parity, you can note that $4S = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1+x^2)/(1+x^4)dx$. Then you don't even need to integrate down the imaginary axis.

Comment: it is better to use upper half plane, since the integrand is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$ I = 2S = \int_0 ^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \ dx,~~~f(x)=\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}$$

According to your OP's method, there are three parts for the contour, $C_1: z=x:x\in [0,R];~C_2: z=Re^{i\theta}: \theta\in [0,\pi/2);~C_3: z=iy: y\in[R, 0]$, and later we let $R\to\infty$

$$\int_{C_1} f(z) \ dz+\int_{C_2} f(z) \ dz+\int_{C_3} f(z) \ dz=2\pi i \cdot Res(z=e^{i\pi/4})$$

On $C_2$ the integral vanishes as $R\to\infty$.

$$\begin{align}\int_{C_1} f(z) \ dz&=\int_0 ^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \ dx\\
\\
\int_{C_3} f(z) \ dz&=\int_\infty ^0 \frac{1+(iy)^2}{1+(iy)^4} ~i dy=-i\int^\infty _0 \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^4} ~ dy\end{align}$$

So we get:

$$\int_0 ^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \ dx-i\int^\infty _0 \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^4} ~ dy=2\pi i\cdot \frac{-i}{2\sqrt2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$$

By comparing the two sides, we get real part of LHS equals the real part of RHS:
$$2S=\int_0 ^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4} \ dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}\Longrightarrow S=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$$

We also get a byproduct, by letting the imaginary part of LHS equals the imaginary part of RHS:

$$i\int^\infty _0 \frac{1-y^2}{1+y^4} ~ dy=0\Longrightarrow \int^\infty _0 \frac{1}{1+y^4} ~ dy=\int^\infty _0 \frac{y^2}{1+y^4} ~ dy$$

and this equation can be easily verified by making substitution $y=\frac{1}t$

Comment: Using "tall things" (like `\displaystyle` or `\dfrac`) in *titles* is [discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730). *Noted seeing you doing this more and more.*

Comment: I don't know that, I have edited.

Comment: These are the details I needed to see, thank you. Usually I wave my hands at integrating over the circumference since it usually goes to zero.